# Shared Variable not starting from zero in SSRS VBA

Tags: vba, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report in SSRS 2014 using a custom vba function that relies on a shared variable. This variable is supposed to contain an aggregate value in conditions where the report includes multiple, related lines.

My problem is that if the first lines of the report are related in this way, then my code ends up being looped several times before the report lines even start to be printed, meaning my aggregate variable starts with a value greater than zero on the first printed line. I don't know why this happens; how can I prevent my function from running if the report line isn't being printed, or otherwise make sure the variable equals zero when the first line to be printed is reached?

EDIT: Here's my code. "lastLine" stores the last line number processed, and is checked against "line" in the function below; if the lines are related, the two values will match.

"lastPick" is my aggregate variable. This number should start at zero, but if the first lines of the report are related, it gets added to prematurely. I have a test case of six related order lines; in this case, "lastPick" starts with a value of 15 for some reason.

The other variables used in the function (rsvd, onHand onward) are various quantities used in calculation of the quantity to pick, stored in variable "calc" for each execution of the function.

```
Shared lastLine As Integer
Dim lastPick As Integer = 0

Function softPick(ByVal line As Integer, ByVal rsvd As Integer, ByVal onHand As Integer, ByVal ord As Integer, ByVal ship As Integer) As Integer

    Dim calc As Integer = 0

If line <> lastLine Or lastLine = 0 Then
  lastPick = 0
End If

    If rsvd <> Nothing And rsvd > 0 Then
        calc = rsvd
    ElseIf onHand <= (ord - ship) Then
        calc = onHand
    ElseIf (ord - ship) > 0 Then
        calc = (ord - ship)
    End If

    If line = lastLine Then
        If ord > onHand Then
            lastPick = lastPick + calc
        Else
            calc = calc - lastPick
        End If
    Else
        lastPick = calc
    End If

    If calc < 0 Then
        calc = 0
    End If

    lastLine = line

    Return calc

End Function
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's pretty difficult to help you debug it.  Post your code...

Comment: @Dave code has been added, with an explanation.

Comment: Calculation order depend on SSRS version. Add a column and call a second function which will increment each time the function is called. Display the function value in order to understand in which order functions are calculated. For SSRS 2005 the order starts from the outer groups to inner eg. Grand Total --> Group1 Item1 --> Group2 Item1 --> Detail --> Group2 Item2 --> Detail ...

Comment: @niktrs Is there a way to check which group is being worked on when running my function? This could be the solution.

Comment: Add another cell next to the one which calls your function, with a counter function and display this number. This will show you the execution order.